# Hi, I want to implement path planning algorithm(A star) on turtle-bot

Tags: ros, amcl-demo.launch, pathplanning

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I want to implement path planning algorithm(A star) on turtle-bot.

Is it possible to do along with amcl demo.

How can i read the obstacles in the map? And how the cost of some position in the map can be changed if i want some places in the map to be avoided.

Can someone suggest me how to go with it.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/149526/hi,-i-want-to-implement-path-planning-algorithm(a-star)-on-turtle-bot./) by [Chennamaneni](https://answers.ros.org/users/14121/chennamaneni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What you're looking to do is implement your own global planner (interface: base_global_planner).

Read about how all the pieces link together in http://wiki.ros.org/navigation and http://wiki.ros.org/nav_core.

What you're really doing is creating a subclass of http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/nav_core/html/classnav__core_1_1BaseGlobalPlanner.html, overriding the two methods to implement your functionality.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1